# Change body background using css modules

Tags: css, reactjs, css-modules, react-css-modules

How do I change a single page background, using scss module and react.

I have this one page component using this;

```
body {
  background: $black;
  background: linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    $black 0%,
    $gray 45%,
    $gray 55%,
    $black 100%
  );
}
```

Other components can not override this body declaration.

how should I proceed, once I need pages with different backgrounds?